# document.getElementById() not working inside uib-tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When my `DOM` element is outside the `uib-tab` ,then it is working fine

## Html:

```
<input type="file" id="clickMe"/>
   <uib-tab>

   </uib-tab>
```

## angular controller :

```
console.log(document.getElementById('clickMe'));
```

And giving me the desired result.

But when i am putting my `DOM element` inside the `uib-tab`, then

Html:

```
<uib-tab>
    <input type="file" id="clickMe"/>
</uib-tab>
```

## controller:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('clickMe'));
```

giving me `null`.

Please Help.

Comment: inspect in elements and verify that <input type="file" id="clickMe"/> is present in html, when you access the id.Maybe it takes time to render on browser and you are using the DOM Accessor before rendering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you are trying to console while page is still **not rendered completely**.
You should try wrap it with `$timeout`, which equal with `document.ready`.

refer this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cp01eLRkNKH2oAMwCDQM?p=preview).